# Multi-line Typewriting Form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fiddling around with a form I seen used on this page (https://conceptstudio.am/say-hello/), I am trying to recreate something similar for a website I am making.

My issue is that I am unsure how to achieve the line-by-line typing effect, I've seen loads of CSS versions but as I have label and span tags this isn't entirely possible. I can achieve each line typing on its own but it spans across the entire div column which usually exceeds the last letter, or it types the entire paragraph as one. I've tried an CSS animation delay also which didn't work.

I'm wondering if it would be better via JS using maybe template strings or something else? Does anyone know a decent method for this? How would I achieve the input fields? I haven't tried much JS in this yet as not sure where to start, seen a few examples but didn't work great with this code.

Heres what I have, please note this is just a (really bad) trial so far:

```
      <form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form">
<div class="typewriter">
                    <p class="form-name" data-name="Hello, I'm  " data-iname="insert your name" data-company="from " data-cmpany-name="your company" style="display: inline-block;">

                    <label class="nname">Hello, I'm </label><span data-placeholder="insert your name" contenteditable="true" class="name placeholder">insert your name</span><span class="your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span><label class="cname">from </label><span data-placeholder="your company" contenteditable="true" class="company  placeholder">your company</span><span class="your-company"><input type="text" name="your-company" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span><span class="dot" style="display: inline;">.</span></p><br><p class="form-textarea" data-text="I'm interested in " data-name="message" style="display: inline-block;"><label>I'm interested in </label><span data-placeholder="message" class="span placeholder" contenteditable="true">message</span><span class="your-message placeholder"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span><span class="dot placeholder" style="display: inline;">.</span></p>
                    <p style="display: block"><br></p>
                    <p class="form-mail" data-text="Here's my " data-name="email address" style="display: inline-block;"><label>Here's my </label><span data-placeholder="email address" class="span placeholder" contenteditable="true">email address</span><span class="your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span><span class="dot" style="display: inline;">.</span></p><p style="display: block"><br></p><p class="thanks" data-text="Thank you!" style="display: inline-block;">Thank you!</p>
                </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


.typewriter {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}

.contact-form h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans',sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact-form {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    -moz-user-select: element;
    -webkit-user-select: element;
    -ms-user-select: element;
/*    padding: 0 0 260px;*/
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.contact-form p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', sans-serif;
/*    display: none;*/
    margin: 5px 0 0;
}

.contact-form p span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #555;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form button,
.contact-form button,
.contact-form .skip,
.contact-form .skip {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff1ac;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff1ab;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.contact-form textarea {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff1ac;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff1ab;
}
```

And my CodePen: https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/qwYmqw

Comment: You can try to use contenteditable="true".

Comment: I already have that :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this typing effect is to prepare the contents beforehand and append to the parent element using JS logic or CSS effects.

```
// Let's say you have a <div id="typewriter"> </div>

const type = function(){

   // We prepare the contents of that div:
     let text = "Hi there" + "<br>";
     let tags = "<p>What is <input type='text' ... placeholder="your name" /></p>";

     let cnt = 0, len = text.length;
     let elem = document.getElementById("typewriter");
     let interval = setInterval(function(){
           if(cnt >= len){
               clearInterval(interval);
           }
           ++cnt;
           elem.innerHTML += text.charAt(cnt);
     }, 100);

     setTimeout(function(){
         elem.innerHTML += tags;
     }, 100);
}

type();
```

The above code should type each character at an interval of 100ms, and will look can be given more effects using further css or jquery.

Comment: Would this still work as a form in the end however? Thats where I'm a little confused. Please excuse me I'm still learning JS.

Comment: Yes this would. Basically all the contents within a tag scope are text. Browser reads the tags and defines the HTML contents. I think if you are new, instead of attempting to perform dynamic animations or effects, take a look at how Javascript can manipulate the DOM: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp Also if you are interested with jQuery, you can look at how to create and append new HTML elements dynamically: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a look into typewriter.js and that helped a little bit but doesn't seem to print my entire string only the first sentence, but still works as a form also. I'm wondering if that would be more suitable for my skill level. https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs/ - this also doesnt print multi-lines however, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried the code you have given me but it doesn't seem to be working correctly for me.

Comment: Like I said, learn more about DOM manipulation. And if you want to print multiline, you have to do it by JS. In HTML, it might seem like they are on different lines, but actually they are not. They  are just all on the same line. If you want to print multiline, you have to insert a `<br>` in order to insert the new line there.

Comment: It just doesnt seem to be printing my code at all, I think I'll need to find another way as this isn't working for my skill level. But thanks anyway, I'll keep it noted for referencing.

Comment: Check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GLdMwr for a very basic implementation.

Comment: Oh I got something working now actually, I'll update my codepen, now I have to figure out how to eliminate the white space and fix the blinker.